# Printing to a kitchen printer via email

Tags: printers, epson, receipt, network-printers

All,

When someone orders a sandwich from a website, I want to be able to print the order out in a kitchen. Is there a printer that will Poll the email box and when a new one is received it will print it out ?

I can use a laptop that is plugged into the reciept printer if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get printers with cloud printing nowadays. Some let you send an email to a specific email address and it will print it out automatically.

Check this link out for more info on printers and their availability. http://www.google.co.uk/cloudprint/learn/printers.html